# displaying mobile app in a desktop browser

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

Most mobile websites look really horrible in a regular browser - the whole thing is stretched across the entire page and - oh boy!

I would like to showcase a mobile app developed using phonegap/JQuery Mobile by placing its web content online. What is the best way to make it look reasonable?

Option 1. Create a wrapper, which is available on on-mobile site only and calls up the mobile portion using iframe or ajax.

Option 2. Fiddle with media queries and style it appropriately. (I found this option to be unduly hard as JQ Mobile introduces a lot of stuff you'll have to "undo".)

Option 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Option 3: use [Ripple](http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/download), which is a free mobile emulator plugin for Chrome.

Option 4: You could also consider doing some server-side styling (using a User Agent mapping library).  In this scenario you would set *max-width* to say 320px on your HTML body, in cases where your server determines that the request is coming from a desktop browser.

Comment: That will allow it to display properly for the poster, but it won't help her visitors. (unless the site forces them to also download ripple, which will probably not make them happy).

Comment: Good point, @octem - some part of me wants to say - Eh - screw the visitors.  ;-) OK.  I'll behave.